# JQUERY Ajax multi post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```js
var name = "gökhan";
var surname = "sahiner";
var id = 12;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "newlevels.php",
    data: name,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
});
```

Hi i want multi post but I've been searching everywhere and I did not understand 
only i have been found this. how can i post. 3 type

Comment: Create a JSON object and post that.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen PHP can't parse JSON automatically, it expects a URL-encoded string. It will parse that into `$_POST`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, didn't know. I just read about the `php://input` shenanigans to parse a POST body. Yuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. You can create an object and POST the object, you can serialize the form (also an object), or you could simply seperate it with a comma.

```
var name = "gökhan";
var surname = "sahiner";
var id = 12;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'newlevels.php',
    data: { nameI: name, 
            surnameI: surname,
            idI: id
    },
    success: function(rsp){
      //
    },
    fail: function(rsp) {
        // Nothing
    }
});
```

### newlevels.php

```
$Name = $_POST["nameI"];
$Surname = $_POST["surnameI"];
$ID = $_POST["idI"];
```

Comment: Why not use his variables in your example instead of making up completely different ones?

Comment: Because I pulled this from one of my login PHP files. I've updated this to match the posters question for you.

Comment: What's with the `I` after all the key names?

Comment: Stands for "Input". Simply a way to differentiate the actual variable with it's key. Of course, PHP can tell the difference but in the example it just keeps the variables and post keys separate.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with @Timothy , this will work . Also you can have a look below :-

```
var name = "gökhan";
var surname = "sahiner";
var id = 12;
var array = name+'|'+surname+'|'+id ; // Create an array with the variables and pass this array and on the other page just explode it to get the separate values

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "newlevels.php",
  data: array,
  dataType: dataType,
  success: function(){//Your function goes here}
});
```

Comment: That won't work. PHP won't be able to parse that string into `$_POST`. It expects the data to be `name=value&name=value&name=value`.

Comment: Can you try the url as "newlevels.php?array="+array ?

Comment: That would work, but it's kind of silly. Why send a single parameter that you have to split, when you can easily send them as separate parameters?

Comment: You also need to use `encodeURIComponent(array)` to encode the accented character.

Comment: Passing a single parameter will be faster.

Comment: Why is passing `array=name|surname|id` faster than passing `name=name&surname=surname&id=id`? Because it's 15 characters shorter? That's negligible, and you could achieve the same savings with something like `n=name&s=surname&i=id`

Comment: That's one point and another is the system will assign different variables if you send separately and it has to be traced separately at the destination . Many factors work behind , thus it will be better to use one rather than many . And most importantly here the data numbered 3 , in many cases you will need to pass many data at one shot .

Comment: You're going to have to separate them into multiple variables in the server script anyway. Why make it more complicated?

Comment: Is it working after making the changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){ //Expecting the event on a button click  
        var name = "gökhan";
        var surname = "sahiner";
        var id = 12;
        var array = name+'|'+surname+'|'+id ;

        var xmlhttp ;           
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){             
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();             
        }           
        else{               
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");               
        }           
        xmlhttp.open("GET","newlevels.php?array="+array,true);          
        xmlhttp.send();         
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){              
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){                  
                var result = xmlhttp.responseText ;                 
                if (result == 1){                       
                    //Your code for success return                  
                }                   
                else{
                    //Your code if return is not a success
                }                   
            }               
        }           
    });
});
```

Hope this will work, let me know if any error comes.